# How can I pause resource tracking on Chrome or Safari?

Tags: google-chrome, resources, safari, keep-alive

The resource tracking tools in Safari and Chrome are great for visualizing load times of various page components, but the view is totally obscured when keep-alive pings take place periodically (in my case, chartbeat sends a ping every 15 seconds, so all the other load times are compressed into a tiny unhelpful section, while the chartbeat pings are stretched out across the view).

So, it would be great if there was a "pause" button that would stop resource tracking, but retain the current view. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In chrome this is possible under the timeline view; I'm not sure if that's what you mean, but it's the round button in the lower left corner.

Comment: Good tip - this works for Timeline view. However, I'm interested in the Resources view.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best way to accomplish this is to switch over to the Scripts view and click pause (on the *top right* of the tab, not the bottom left). This pauses the chartbeat script execution and effectively pauses the Resources "time" graph view.